# Setup Google OpenId Login

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, openid, google-openid

I'm having a hard time learning how to integrate Google OpenId support to my spring 3.1 web application (including Spring security 3.1).

I've found some documentation and tutorials but it have not helped me enough.

Like:

[Springsource openId documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-openid)

[Solid Craft tutorial on OpenId](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/spring-security-by-example-openid-login.html)

[Opening up to OpenID](http://www.packtpub.com/article/opening-up-to-openid-with-spring-security)

I still can't figure out how to make this work.

What are the components that I need to get a google OpenId login work in the app?
I mean what are the absolute minimum requirements to get this running? nothing extra.

A really simple example would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the Spring Security OpenID sample application?

Comment: No I have not found that one.

Comment: There is a chapter in the manual on sample applications.

Comment: I created a blog by explaining all the process how to create and how to use
https://developersandeep.blogspot.in/2017/03/oauth-authentication-google-facebook.html

Answer (score 0):

Google support for OpenID will removed: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration. You should use OAuth or OpenID Connect support. Both are supported by the https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j library (as well as CAS, SAML, GAE and many other identity providers). See the demo: https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-